# Count non-empty nodes in XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to count all **b** nodes which are not empty (so result should be 2).

```
<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <b/>
  <b>g</b>
</a>
```

I'm using code below but this returns count off all nodes (empty included).

```
select top 1  rc.XmlContent.value('count(//a/b)', 'int') from Table rc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `//a/b/text()` rather than just `//a/b`, then you get a count of 2

```
DECLARE @x XML= '<a><b>1</b><b/><b>g</b></a>';
SELECT @x.value('count(//a/b/text())', 'int');
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this is not the answer! I misread this completely and thought your are looking for the empty nodes. There is an appropriate answer given by GarethD already (same idea, just the other way round).

I don't delete it, because it might help others...

The empty element `<b/>` (same as `<b></b>`) is existing but has no `text()`.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<a>
  <b>1</b>
  <b/>
  <b></b>
  <b>g</b>
</a>';

select @xml.value('count(/a/b[empty(text())])', 'int')
```

This returns 2, because there is `<b/>` and `<b></b>`.

Just for completeness, you might negate the predicate, which is your needed result actually:

```
select @xml.value('count(/a/b[not(empty(text()))])', 'int')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath expression

```
count(/a/b[normalize-space(text())=''])
```

Incorporated in your code it would look like this:

```
select top 1  rc.XmlContent.value('count(/a/b[normalize-space(text())=""])', 'int') from Table rc
```